# How to get Google to index pages which get redirected using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, redirect, seo

I'm using google maps for a website. All the data available via the map on the home page is also listed on other pages throughout the site, but with javascript turned on these pages redirect to the home page: eg http://host.com/county/essex redirects to http://host.com/#county/essex, which makes the map load all the data for Essex.

I'd like Google to index all the pages on my site, as otherwise none of the data included in the map will be searchable. But I know that for very good reasons Google doesn't normally index pages which get redirected. Is there a way to get Google to index my pages. Or, failing that, is there a way to submit all the data to google in some other way?

*edit
All my pages are linked to from my main navigation (it's just that javascript overrides the default link action)... the upshot being that there should be no need for a sitemap as all the pages are discoverable by google bot using normal link following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding submitting data to google, there is a thing called [Google sitemaps](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) that is supposed to notify google of all URIs/locations that exist on a given site and are/should be indexed. Truth is, however, that sites that aren't crawlable by default rarely benefit much from the aforementioned sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [site Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) it allows you to include urls you need indexed.

Comment: I should have added that all my pages are linked to from my main navigation (it's just that javascript overrides the default link action)... the upshot being that there should be no need for a sitemap as all the pages are discoverable by google bot using normal link following

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> with javascript turned on these pages redirect to the home page

Google bot doesn't execute javascript. If your redirects are made in javascript, Google bot will simple index the page and ignore the redirect.

Comment: It may not execute it exactly, but I get the impression they try to sniff out javascript redirects in some way. A few searches using the query eg "site:[mydomain] essex" have convinced me that nothing except my home page is being indexed